# How should I store my aeropress?

Tags: storage, aeropress

I've heard that storing an Aeropress with the plunger inside the main cylinder will eventually damage the plunger, because the rubber is stored compressed.

Is there any truth to this? What's the best way to store an aeropress?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the Aeropress manual:

> Remove the cap and set it aside.  Push the plunger to eject the "puck"
>   of spent grounds into the trash.  Rinse and/or brush away any grounds
>   left on the rubber seal.  The seal has already wiped your chamber
>   clean, so no further cleanup is needed.
>
> Always eject the puck right after brewing, and *store your Aeropress
>   with the plunger pushed all the way through or completely removed. 
>   Storing the seal uncompressed will keep your seal airtight for years.*
>
> ([source](http://aerobie.com/images/AeroPress%20Instr%20English%20Rev.B.pdf) [pdf])